# should wrong questions be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked a wrong question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577960/autoloading-folder-zendx-jquery-and-others. what i did was i wrote ZendX_jQuery instead of ZendX_JQuery (case sensitivity). i was thinking that lots of people make same mistakes like beginners like myself. now i was wondering should if i should delete questions or make correction with explanation so that others might find help?

EDIT: link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577960/autoloading-folder-zendx-jquery-and-others

Comment: thanks; also, looka here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a simple typo which doesn't change the meaning, then just fix it and don't think too much about it.

If it does change the meaning of your question, then fix it and make the change easy to spot to people who saw the first version. You could add something like:

EDIT: Changed ZendX_jQuery to ZendX_JQuery (case sensitivity)

To the start of your question, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

There are no answers yet, so if that was a typo in the question I would correct it and make note of this edit in the comments. If there were some answers, I'd make the update clear, at the same time noting that the original answers were originally correct but didn't solve your problem.

If there were detailed answers that helped you solve the stated question, I'd accept the most helpful answer and ask a new question. In this case, you don't want to create big confusion with upvoted answers looking like they're answering the wrong question. At the same time, you don't want to upset those who spent time answering your question. Someone else might make the same mistake, and leaving your question alive leaves them with a chance of finding the good answers.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no answers and you think the question is no longer relevant and won't help anybody else there is no harm in deleting it.

On the other hand, if other people might make the same mistake and you think the question with an according answer might help them, don't delete it. Instead post as an answer that the reason for the problems was this simple typo. Accept this answer to make it clear that this was the solution to the problem.